# submatrix with unique colname

Tags: r

I have very big matrix. most of the columns have same names. I just want to get a submatrix from my original matrix, such that, the number of the rows is the same as original one, but for the columns, just want to have one column from columns with the same name.

```
>data
  A A  B  C  C
p 1 5  9 13 17
q 2 6 10 14 18
l 3 7 11 15 19
m 4 8 12 16 20
```

expected output :

```
 A  B  C
p 1  9 13
q 2 10 14
l 3 11 15
m 4 12 16
```

how can I use `subset ()` or other function do do this ?

Answer (score 4):

You can use `duplicated` to identify the columns to remove.

```
data[ , ! duplicated(colnames(data)) ]
```